# Setting recipient authentication options on Envelope creation

Tags: docusignapi

When sending an Envelope through the API and opening that envelope, the recipient is redirect to KBA (knowledge-based authentication) security. I've been looking for a way to turn this off. In the Docusign Admin panel, I can switch this off for Envelopes that are sent manually, and all goes well. However, when sending these envelopes through the API, there is still KBA enforced on the recipient. Is there any way to disable this when creating the envelope.

Please note that this is only an issue since switching from sandbox to production. When testing with a sandbox account, this has never been an issue. Using the same code after upgrading my integrator key to a production account however, this happens. Is there any reason why Docusign makes a difference in this regard?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check with your admin. This setting is controlled in account level.

Comment: I am the admin of the account. As mentioned; "In the Docusign Admin panel, I can switch this off for Envelopes that are sent manually", but this doesn't work for the API apparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution. Turns out it was probably a small bug in the Docusign services. I have been waiting for a full week, going back and forth with the Docusign support desk (who of course don't do API stuff, but I had to try since there was no-one answering here). After a while I decided to try flicking the switch in the Admin panel a bit more, out of desperation.

It turns out, after at least three times flicking KBA on and off, suddenly I could send envelopes without signers needing to go through KBA.

So, if you are out there, on the off-change you walk into this same problem: In the Admin panel, there is a "Security Settings" section. In there, you can find the "Recipient Authentication Settings" header. In there, select the appropriate option for you (probably either one of "Sender can require that a recipient must authenticate" or "Disable recipient authentication". Try switching between them a few times if it doesn't work for you. Shouldn't be the fix, but it worked for me.

Oh, by the way, thank you Docusign for taking a full week to carefully consider answering my question. It was a blast waiting on you for nothing.